# 2 vs. 1.005^200

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Without using a calculator or a computer can you determine which of these two numbers is bigger: $2$ or $1.005^{200}$ ?

I saw this puzzle in a YouTube video, which I will post later.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> We can write,
>
> $$\begin{align}1.005^{200}&=\left(1+\frac1{200}\right)^{200}\\&=\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1{200}\right)\left(1+\frac1{200}\right)\left(1+\frac1{200}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac1{200}\right)}_{200\text{ terms}}\end{align}$$
>
> And
> $$\begin{align}2&=\frac{201}{200}\frac{202}{201}\frac{203}{202}\cdots\frac{400}{399}\\&=\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1{200}\right)\left(1+\frac1{201}\right)\left(1+\frac1{202}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac1{399}\right)}_{200\text{ terms}}\end{align}$$
>
> As the denominator gets bigger, the number gets smaller. So we can clearly see
>
> $$\boldsymbol{1.005^{200}\gt2}$$

Comment: I've not seen this one before. Very nice!

Comment: Agree. This was very nice.

Comment: This is the nice solution I was looking for. Well done. It is described in this video: https://youtu.be/CN59vNllv7g

Comment: What an elegant answer!

Comment: It took a moment to realize where the expansion of 2 came from. A helpful step for us less mathematically inclined could be 2=400/200=400/200*201/201*202/202*...*399/399 and then rearranging.

Comment: Falco, thanks. You'd think the ACB would have such courtesy.

Answer (score 34):

This is quite easy if you know

> the binomial theorem

or

> compound interest.

The largest of the two numbers is

> $1.005^{200}$.
>  By the binomial theorem
>  $$(a+b)^{200} = a^{200} + \binom{200}{1} a^{199}b^1  + \binom{200}{2} a^{198}b^2 + ...$$
>  Since $1.005= 1+\frac{1}{200}$, we can put $a=1$ and $b=\frac{1}{200}$ to find that
>  $$\left(1+\frac{1}{200}\right)^{200} = 1^{200} + 200\cdot 1^{199}\left(\frac{1}{200}\right)^1 + ... = 2 + ...$$
>
>  Another way to see it, is by thinking of compound interest. Multiplying by $1.005$ is a half percent increase, and $200$ times such an increase is a $100\%$ increase if you do not take compound interest into account. So it doubles without the compound interest, and more than doubles with the compound interest. So multiplying by $1.005^{200}$ is more than multiplying by $2$.

Comment: This is clearly the intended solution. It's no coincidence that 0.005 is 1/200.

Comment: Also Bernoulli's inequality, which can be proved without knowing the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 24):

> Multiplying a number $x$ by $1.005$ is equivalent to adding $0.005x$ to $x$. When $x > 1$, $0.005x > 0.005$. Therefore, when $1.005$ is multiplied  by itself, the result is greater than $1.005 + 0.005$, when it's multiplied by itself twice, the result is greater than $1.005 + 0.005 + 0.005$, and so on. $1.005^{200}$, or $1.005$ multiplied by itself $199$ times, is therefore greater than $0.005$ added to $1.005$ 199 times. In other words, $1.005^{200} > 1.005 + 0.005 \cdot 199 = 1.005 + 0.995 = 2$.

Something I noticed when I double-checked my answer:

> $1.005^{200}$ is quite close to Euler's constant since, when $n$ tends to infinity, $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ approaches $e$, and $1.005^{200}$ equals $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ where $n = 200$.

Based on the observation above and a comment by [Dmitry Kamenetsky](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/62537/dmitry-kamenetsky), here's another solution to the puzzle:

> When $n > 0$, $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is strictly increasing. Below is my incomplete attempt to prove that, but I'm not great at maths so please tell me if there's anything I should correct.

> $$\begin{align*} f(n) &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \\ f'(n) &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \left(\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) n\right)' \\ &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \left(\left(\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right)' \cdot n + (n)' \cdot \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})\right) \\ &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \left( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}} \cdot (1 + \frac{1}{n})' \cdot n + 1 \cdot \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})\right) \\ &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \left( \frac{n}{n + 1} \cdot (n^{-1})' \cdot n + \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \\ &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \left( \frac{n}{n + 1} \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \cdot n + \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \end{align*}$$

> If both factors in $f'(n)$ are greater than $0$ when $n > 0$, $f'(n)$ is greater than $0$ when $n > 0$ and $f(n)$ is strictly increasing when $n > 0$.

> Proving that the first factor, $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, is greater than $0$ is quite simple. $\frac{1}{n}$, and therefore also $1 + \frac{1}{n}$, are greater than $0$ when $n > 0$, and raising a number greater than $0$ to a real power yields a number greater than $0$.

> I was not able to prove that the second factor is always greater than $0$ for $n > 0$, but [@isaacg](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2187/isaacg) did in [his own answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122005/85496), so please check out that one.

> Anyway, assuming $f(n)$ is strictly increasing when $n > 0$, $f(200)$, which equals $1.005^{200}$, is greater than $f(1)$, which equals $2$.

Comment: Nice observation about Euler's constant. Perhaps that alone is enough to find the bigger number.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky It [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Inequalities). (Use the right (!) inequality.)

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky That's probably true! $(1 + frac{1}{n})^n$ is, after all, strictly increasing when $n > 0$, so the result when $n$ equals $200$ must be greater than the result when $n$ equals $1$ (which is $2$). I might add a more formal proof for this to my answer later :)

Comment: Nice approach! I completed your proof that (1+1/n)^n is strictly increasing, see my answer.

Comment: Thank you, @isaacg! I'll edit my answer to mention yours :)

Answer (score 21):

We can also use [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality), the inequality between the arithmetic and geometric means, applied to 199 1s and one 2:

> $1.005 = \frac{\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1+1}^{199 \text{ terms}}+2}{200}>\sqrt[200]{\underbrace{1\times 1\times\cdots\times 1\times 1}_{199 \text{ terms}}\times 2} = \sqrt[200] 2$

Comment: that is very neat!

Answer (score 14):

There is binominal formula, first two terms of which is impossible to forget:

> $$\displaystyle (1+x)^{n}=1+nx+...$$

so clearly

> $$1.005^{200} > 1 + 1$$

Comment: This is true as long as all other terms are positive, which is true in this specific case.

Answer (score 10):

For a quick estimation of doubling, we can apply

> the [rule of 72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72)

The "initial capital" is 1, and the "interest rate is 0.005, or 0.5%.

> $$\frac{72}{0.5} = 72 \times 2 = 144$$

Therefore

> $$1.005^{144} ≈ 2 < 1.005^{200}$$

Comment: I am impressed that you were able to find a close approximation to 2 with rule of 72. Although rule of 70 gives even a better approximation.

Answer (score 8):

I've got the simplest answer.

> $(1+x)^2=1^2+2x+x^2 > 1+2x$ if $x>0$, and this obviously extends to $(1+x)^n > 1+nx$.
>  
>  So $(1+0.005)^{200}>1+200*0.005=1+1=2$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: This is essentially the first half of @Jaap's answer.

Comment: Ok you did in one step that which took me two.

Comment: When you say *"this obviously extends to..."*, do you mean *"I could prove by induction that..."*?

Comment: @Stef One can use binomial theorem again to prove that...

Comment: @Mihail I think the whole point of this answer is to **not** rely on the binomial theorem.

Comment: @Stef personally, if we rely on binomial theorem for $n=2$, then it's not far away from general $n$. Binomial theorem is an ubiquitos trick and there is no reason to shy away from it. But eventually only Spitemaster can tell what's the point, he endowed, in his answer.

Answer (score 6):

I feel like a lot of these answers are incredibly complicated... All you need is one simple multiplication.

> 1.005^200 = 1 + 0.005 * 200 + that compounding stuff, let's call it C.
>  0.005 * 200=1.
>  So 1.005^200 = 1+1+C. C "obviously" (if you know how compounding works that is) is >0, so 1+1+C > 2.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to continue @Peter's approach of showing that $f(n) = (1+1/n)^n$ is increasing over the interval $n>0$. Peter showed that

> $$f'(n) = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n \cdot ( \frac{n}{n + 1} \cdot (-\frac{1}{n^2}) \cdot n + \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})) $$
>  Because $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ is clearly positive, we just need to show that
>  $$( \frac{n}{n + 1} \cdot (-\frac{1}{n^2}) \cdot n + \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})) > 0$$

Let's simplify this term:

> $$ \frac{n}{n + 1} \cdot (-\frac{1}{n^2}) \cdot n + \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n}) = -\frac{1}{n+1} + \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})$$

So all we need to show is that

> $$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) \ge \frac{1}{n+1}$$

To prove this, let us apply

> the [lower bound of the natural logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lower_Bound_of_Natural_Logarithm), which states that
>  $$ \ln x \ge 1-\frac{1}{x}$$
>  Applying this with $x=1+\frac{1}{n}$, we find that
>  $$ \ln (1+\frac{1}{n}) \ge 1 - \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} = 1 - \frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

This completes the proof that $f'(n) > 0$, as desired.

Comment: This also follows from the mean value theorem: $\log 1+ \frac 1  n = \log n+1 - \log n = \frac 1 \nu$ for some $\nu$ strictly between $n$ and $n+1$.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, a simple solution is to look at the first few terms of the binomial expansion of $\left(1+ \frac{1}{200}\right)^{200}$:
$$1 + \frac{200}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{200} + \frac{200\cdot199}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{200^2} + \cdots$$
which is clearly $>2$.

---

It has also been mentioned that for large $x$, $(1+ \frac{1}{x})^{x} \approx e$. In fact, it can be shown that for $x>0$,
$$\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} < e < \left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$$
and hence
$$e\approx\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1/2}$$
We can use this approximation to give a better estimate of  $a=\left(1+ \frac{1}{200}\right)^{200}$, without a calculator.

We have
$$e\approx\left(1+ \frac{1}{200}\right)^{200+1/2}$$
So
$$a\approx e \left(1+ \frac{1}{200}\right)^{-1/2}$$

For small $u$, $\frac{1}{1+u}\approx 1-u$.
Also, $(1+u)^2\approx 1+2u$, so $\sqrt{1+u}\approx 1+u/2$.
Thus, $\left(1+ \frac{1}{200}\right)^{-1/2} \approx \left(1- \frac{1}{400}\right)$ and so $a\approx e\left(1- \frac{1}{400}\right)$

Now, we just need an approximation of $e$. Any student of calculus *should* know that $e\approx2.71828$, but it's easy enough to calculate a few decimals by hand from the Taylor series:
$$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!}$$
The first few sums for $e$ are

| i | S(i) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1/1 |
| 1 | 2/1 |
| 2 | 5/2 |
| 3 | 16/6 |
| 4 | 65/24 |
| 5 | 326/120 |
| 6 | 1957/720 |
| 7 | 13700/5040 |

The last row gives us $e\approx 2.71825$. Subtracting $2.71825/400$ gives $a\approx 2.71145$. A high precision calculation of $a$ gives $2.7115171229293747985490$, so that approximation isn't too shabby.

FWIW, apart from the final high precision calculation, I performed all of the arithmetic by hand, but I checked it with a calculator.

---

Incidentally, there's an alternative way to calculate $e$ related to $e\approx\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1/2}$. It's more convenient to make the power an integer: $e\approx\left(1+ \frac{1}{x-1/2}\right)^x$, and if $x$ is a binary power we can do exponentiation by repeated squaring.

We can do even better. Let
$$e=\left(1+ \frac{1}{x-1/2 + y}\right)^x$$
Then we can find $y$ from the continued fraction expansion of $e^{1/x}$.
We get $y=$
$$\cfrac{1}{12x + \cfrac{1}{5x + \cfrac{1}{28x + \cfrac{1}{9x + \cdots\vphantom{\cfrac{1}{1}}}}}}$$
See https://oeis.org/A110185 for more coefficients, which come from an interleaved pair of arithmetic progressions. Using just the terms shown above for $y$ with $x=256$, we get $e=2.7182818284590452353602874713526627$, which is accurate to 110 bits.

Comment: Some fascinating trivia about e. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you like it @Dmitry! You may enjoy https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1295561/207316 which has Python code to calculate large numbers of digits of e (without using arbitrary precision arithmetic).

Comment: Very cool, thank you. That's the first time I've seen the factorial base used for anything useful.

Answer (score 5):

A solution using the Mean Value Theorem:

> We wish to determine whether $1.005^{200} - 2$ is positive or negative, or equivalently, whether $1005^{200} - 2 \times 1000^{200}$ is positive or negative. We may isolate this quantity as $(1005^{200} - 1000^{200}) - 1000^{200}$, and the part within the parentheses is of the form $f(1005) - f(1000)$ for $f(x) = x^{200}$, which is what gave me the idea.

> The mean value theorem yields $1005^{200} - 1000^{200} = f(1005) - f(1000) = 5 \times f'(\xi)$ for some $1000 < \xi < 1005$, and thus
>  $$ 1005^{200} - 1000^{200} = 5 \times 200 \times \xi^{199} = 1000 \times \xi^{199}. $$

> The fact that $5 \times 200 = 1000$ is fortunate, and allows us to see that $1005^{200} - 1000^{200} = 1000 \times \xi^{199} > 1000^{200}$, and thus $(1005^{200} - 1000^{200}) - 1000^{200} > 0$, whence $1.005^{200} - 2 > 0$ and hence $1.005^{200} > 2$.

Answer (score 0):

> Since (1+a)²=1+2a+a²
>  As a²>0,
>  (1+a)²>1+2a
>  1.005²>1.01
>  1.005⁴>1.01²>1.02

Similarly,

> (1+a)⁵⁰>1+50a
>  1.02⁵⁰>1+50(0.02)=1+1=2

Combining the results:

> 1.005²⁰⁰=(1.005⁴)²⁰>2

Comment: Hi. I don't quite follow the logic. In the first block I understand that you're showing by induction that $(1 + a)^{(2^n)} > 1 + 2^n a$; but then in the second block you conclude that $(1+a)^{50} > 1 + 50a$, even though 50 is not a power of 2.

Comment: Read some of the other answers. They explain it better and you will get a general feel of the solution.

Comment: I don't see any induction here, just using Bernoulli's inequality twice when it could be used directly on 200.

Comment: I agree. It's not the neatest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof of Bernoulli's inequality:

> For $n > 1$, $f(x) = (1 + x)^n$ is strictly convex over $x > -1$ as its second derivative is $(n-1)(n)(x+1)^{n-2} > 0$.

> So by convexity, $f$ lies above its tangent line at $x=0$, that is for $x \ne 0$, $(1+x)^n = f(x) > f(0) + f'(0)x = 1 + nx$. The puzzle follows from $x = 1/200, n=200$.